# IE right property off page - vertical scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery at this page to slide out the couch to the right, it works fine in FF as you can see, but in IE 6 you have vertical scrolling.

I had numerous other IE issues, but I got rid of most of them, by going through my CSS again and tightening up the lose ends.

http://www.catonthecouchproductions.com/new/

I have tried many things, googled various IE css/right issues but nothing. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this so it appears as it does in FF?

Comment: As a side note, your tooltips for the images along the bottom are displaying error text  :)

Comment: Thanks! Using just an integer as an XHTML ID, isnt valid, so I added a "p" - But I need to change the php backend. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
html, body { width:100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}
```

In your IE6 style section

Tested (in a way - the scripts don't work in stupid IETester, you tell me if it works) on a locally-saved version of your site - you might have to add the same rules to the body as well

Btw, I personally prefer to write compliant CSS to my heart's content and then make a whole bunch of ugly hacks for IE6 in a separate `ie6-evil-hacks.css` file (as opposed to going over the CSS and tightening loose ends). Not having to code *around* IE6 is a liberating experience.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I've read it as "horizontal scrolling", because that's what bugged me - the site is too big in my IETester anyway, so it *needs* vertical scrolling. Obviously, if you want to get rid of both, it's `overflow: hidden` instead of `overflow-x:hidden`.